# How to make vertical bar smaller?

Tags: r

My R code

```
#!/usr/bin/R

library(vcd)

fcm <-c(13.0,12.5,11.8)
gk  <-c(10.9 ,   10.5  ,  10.2)
gg  <-c(12.0 ,   11.0 ,   10.8)
data <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data) <- c(5,6,7)

barplot(as.matrix(data),ylim=c(0,13),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), 
       fill = c( "red", "black", "green"))
```

I was and I am happy with the image.The problem is that I have submitted this and many other images for publication in scientific journal.One of the reviwers complained that images like this should be made smaller because of space problems.Any ideas how to make vertical bars smaller,but to keep the main information visible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but do you know `png()` (and the like)? That would allow you to specify a height and width. (Also, just out of interest: what do you use the `vcd` package for?)

Comment: @maj Will try with png().Yeah I guess I do not need vcd package here!